# RIP Syd Mead - concept artist in Blade Runner & Tron

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

[Syd Mead](http://sydmead.com/), legendary futurist and concept artist in *Blade Runner* and *Tron*, among other works, [has died](https://kotaku.com/syd-mead-has-died-1840730705) at the age of 86.

[image]

He was [considered by many](https://twitter.com/CyberpunkGame/status/1211977622550437888) as one of the fathers of the cyberpunk genre.

RIP Syd

Comment: There is still an exhibition of his works (including *this* picture above) in Berlin: https://ortner-ortner.com/de/baukunst/aktuelles/syd-mead

Comment: Who *downvotes* an RIP post???

Comment: @desertnaut: replicants?

Answer (score 8):

## His iconic and stunning visuals are beautiful and will be missed, what an absolute legend!

[image][image]

[image][image]

https://www.flickr.com/photos/db742/sets/72157626600757436/

Comment: Indeed (last image looks void?)

Comment: @desertnaut Seems to be a browser error.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica-M.Schröder you're right, doesn't display in Firefox but it does in Chrome

Comment: Is that sumo wrestling on the display in the last picture?